# How to add an input field from ts file to html file in angular?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular4-forms

I have the following code in html file as follows.
samplecomponent.html

```
<div class="col-12">
    <form >
        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control">
        <button>Add field</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now on clicking add field I have to generate a text field with some name. Text fields must be generated as per the clicking of add field button. If we press add field two times two fields must populate. How to acheive this? Any suggestions, walk-throughs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ngFor` to loop the inputs

```
<div class="col-12">
    <form >
        <input *ngFor="let item of items" [(ngModel)]="item.fName" type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control">
        <button (click)="addNew()">Add field</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

And then add a method to push an item to the array when the button click

```
export class AppComponent  {
  items: Object[];


  constructor(){
    this.items = [];
  }

  addNew(): void {
    this.items.push({
      name:'',
      id: this.items.length + 1
    }) // push what ever you want
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdz9ge?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)